# Inaccessible cardinal in a transitive model

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

If  $\mathfrak M$ is a transitive model of ZFC and $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $\mathfrak M$.

Proof. If $\alpha<\kappa$ then since $\mathfrak M \models$ AC, we must have
either $(2^{\alpha})^\mathfrak M<\kappa$ or $(2^{\alpha})^\mathfrak M \geq\kappa$ and the letter is impossible since $2^\alpha < \kappa.$
I do not follow here this last statement "**since**". However I understand that
$|\alpha|\leq|\alpha|^\mathfrak M$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you assuming the universe of your model is a proper class?

Comment: The statement is false as written, which is why I asked the question in the comment above.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have a copy from the Jech's book which I  put here.I think Jech means a **set** model.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Please see the two relevant pages from Jech's book.

Comment: Inner models are by definition proper class models.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Right. You have the statement on the first page in the snippet. Is it really wrong ? Or, when replaced by a **proper class**, renders it correct ?

Comment: The statement is correct for inner models, which are proper classes. It is false, as written, for some transitive set models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an inclusion $(2^\alpha)^\mathfrak{M} \subseteq 2^\alpha$, so if $(2^\alpha)^\mathfrak{M} \geq \kappa$, then $\kappa \leq (2^\alpha)^\mathfrak{M} \leq 2^\alpha$, which is impossible because $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: Why use a contradiction at all?

Comment: @Andrés The proof OP posted used that as well. I'm just explaining the one sentence OP asks about.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Your answer is very good, it's helped. I always struggle with these one line chains of cardinal inequalities.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Where did you use that $\mathfrak M$ is transitive ? And  where $|\alpha|\leq|\alpha|^\mathfrak M$ ?

Comment: @user122424 The first inclusion I mention uses the fact that $\mathfrak{M}$ is transitive (it means that the element of relation is the real one). It is also implicitly used by the fact that any injection in $\mathfrak{M}$ would be an injection in the universe as well. The fact $|\alpha| \leq |\alpha|^\mathfrak{M}$ is not used.